# How do i solve problem in odd number in turtle, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

```
height = input("Enter the height: ")
height = int(height)
width = input("Enter the width: ")
width = int(width)

import turtle

width = width - 1

turtle.speed(1)

turtle.penup()

for y in range(height // 2):
    for x in range(width):
        turtle.dot()
        turtle.forward(20)
        turtle.dot()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.right(90)
    for x in range(width):
        turtle.dot()
        turtle.forward(20)
        turtle.dot()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.left(90)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

[image]

I want to print dots in python graphical turtle. For my width, it’s giving out as my input. But for the height, if the number is even I am getting the accurate output but if the number is odd I am getting height - 1. I know that my code, logic are not efficient & accurate. I am a self-learner (by books only).

Comment: Your code always draws an even number of rows because `for x in range(width):` is used in the outer loop twice. There is no way your code can draw an odd number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than patch your nested loops, let's simplify them:

```
import turtle

height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
width = int(input("Enter the width: "))

turtle.speed('slowest')
turtle.penup()

angle = 90

for _ in range(height):
    for _ in range(width - 1):
        turtle.dot()
        turtle.forward(20)

    turtle.dot()

    turtle.right(angle)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.right(angle)

    angle *= -1

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.exitonclick()
```